# How can I get data from two collection in one Get request using mongoDB and node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

**Node js  js with MongoDB Get Request**

My 1st collection `registers` contains user details.
My 2nd collection `plans` contains plan details.
I get my plan collection data with `req.body._id`

my get request code

```
userPlanGetControl: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await plans.findOne({_id:req.body._id}).populate("registers").exec((err,docs)=>{
        if(err) return handleError(err);
        res.send(docs);
      });
      
    } catch (error) {
      res.send(error);
    }
  },
```

my postman response

```
{
    "_id": "620f99c6f323f62d4c3c8f9b",
    "User": "620e12610449b7a382aa0266",
    "PlaneName": "Gold",
    "planDuration": "6 months",
    "PlaneAmount": 199,
    "StartDate": "18-02-2022",
    "EndDate": "18-08-2022",
    "planStatus": "Active",
    "__v": 0
}
```

but I nee This type of Object

```
{
    "_id": "620f99c6f323f62d4c3c8f9b",
    "User": {
        "_id": "620e12610449b7a382aa0266",
        "username": "mariSelvan",
        "email": "mari1226@gmail.com",
        "mobile": 917708472804,
        "todayDate": "2022-02-17T09:16:17.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "PlaneName": "Gold",
    "planDuration": "6 months",
    "PlaneAmount": 199,
    "StartDate": "18-02-2022",
    "EndDate": "18-08-2022",
    "planStatus": "Active"
}
```

Comment: try aggregation with lookup

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you want to use .populate("registers") you also need to have your User in your schema be something like this :

```
User: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'registers' }
```

I assume the ref is registers, if not then it would be whatever Model name you chose for the schema you want that info in User to come from. (edit: you would also need to change the actual call to populate to be .populate('User'); the argument should be the name of the field you want to replace)

Comment: yes man I already use this type

  `const planSchema = new Schema(
  {
    User: {
      type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'registers',
    },
    PlaneName: {
      type: String,
    },
    planDuration: {
      type: String,
    },
    PlaneAmount: {
      type: Number,
    },
    StartDate:{
      type:String
    },
    EndDate:{
      type:String
    },
    planStatus:{
      type:String
    }
  },
  
);
const plan = mongoose.model("plans", planSchema);
module.exports = plan;`

Comment: And you tried changing the argument of populate() to "User"?

Comment: no... the populate method is not working for me... that is my issue